# How a for loop can put text in 3 JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, while-loop, jtextarea

I have an API that it has a for loop and prints out the weather condition of the next 3 days.

```
for (ForecastForday1 day : forecast) 
          {
            // Print out what day the forecast is for, and
            // the conditions on that day
            System.out.println("The weather on " + day.getDayOfWeek()
                   + " will be " + day.getInfo("Conditions"));
          }
```

But I have 3 JTextArea so each I want each time that the loop repeats it put data in one text area, and then the next one.

My text areas:

```
day1.append("");
day2.append("");
day3.append("");
```

So I guess I have to put a loop over this loop but dont know where to start.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like following if you can use Array of textareas rather than 3 DIFFERENT VARIABLES

```
JTextArea  days[] = new JTextArea[3];
        int i=0;   
        for (ForecastForday1 day : forecast)  {
            days[i++].append("Append string");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

i can suggest one way out of the many ways possible to go about this,

```
    int i=0;   
    for (ForecastForday1 day : forecast) 
                  {
                    if (i%3==0)
                       day1.append("string here");
                    else if (i%3==1)
                       day2.append("string here");
                    else if (i%3==2)
                       day3.append("string here");

                    i++;
                    // Print out what day the forecast is for, and
                    // the conditions on that day
                    System.out.println("The weather on " + day.getDayOfWeek()
                           + " will be " + day.getInfo("Conditions"));
                  }
```

i think this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it prints all in the day1 (the first text area). :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? 
Tell me if this helps or if it needs tweaking.

```
 {

ArrayList<JTextArea> list = new ArrayList<JTextArea>() ;

list.add(day1);
//add day2 and day3 etc

Int i=0;
for (ForecastForday1 day : forecast) 
          {
           //add check to see of list size is greater than i

             list.get(i).append( //day data);
            i=i+1;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Thank you @redDevil for his help. It gave me the idea.

```
    int i=0;   
    for (ForecastForday1 day : forecast) 
    {

          if (i==0){
             day1Weather.append("The weather on " + day.getDayOfWeek() + " will be " + day.getInfo("Conditions")");
          }
          else if (i==1){
             day2Weather.append("The weather on " + day.getDayOfWeek() + " will be " + day.getInfo("Conditions")");
          }
          else if (i==2){
             day3Weather.append("The weather on " + day.getDayOfWeek() + " will be " + day.getInfo("Conditions")");
          }
          i++;
    }
```